# Each basis of $V^*$ is dual of a basis of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Question :
Assume that $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space.
Prove that each basis of $V^*$ is dual of a basis of $V$.

My try :

I defined an isomorphism this way :

$i : V \to V^{**}$
For each $v \in V$, $i$ takes $v$ and gives $i(v)$.

What is $i(v)$? Its a linear-transformation.
$i(v):V^* \to F$
$(i(v))(f)=f(v)$

I proved that this transformation is linear and one-to-one. Then i concluded that its an isomorphism.  ( The details are not important cause i've done that and its not my problem. )

To prove the theorem, Take an arbitrary basis of $V^*$ like $C$.  Find the dual of $C$ ( call it $C^*$ ) which is in $V^{**}$. Using the isomorphism $i$, Consider the inverted image of the members of $C^*$ in $V$. This set is a basis of $V$. Call it $B$.

Now, I need to prove that $B^*=C$.  That's where i'm stuck.

Note 1 : There is a similar question. But its closed and i don't wan't that methods for proving this theorem. I want to complete my proof.

Comment: Well, since $c^*_j(c_k)=\delta_{jk}$, and $c_k(i^{-1}(c^*_j))=c^*_j(c_k)$ by construction of $i(\cdot)$, you don't need to prove much more.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan I'm confused with your indices and names ... please make it more readable ... or give some explanation ...

Comment: Here $c_k\in C$, $c^*_j\in C^*$, so $B=\{i^{-1}(c^*_j)\mid c^*_j\in C^*\}$. For every $b_j\in B$ you take $c^*_j=i(b_j)$ and the duality follows.

Comment: You are mixing up a couple of things here. Proving $V, V^{**}$ isomorphic isn't going to show that $V, V^*$ are isomorphic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea is good! In order not to confuse indices, let me call $\omega\colon V\to V^{**}$ the isomorphism.

Consider $\{\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n\}$ a basis of $V^*$ and its dual basis $\{\xi_1^*,\dots,\xi_n^*\}$ in $V^{**}$. This has the property that
$$
\xi_i^*(\xi_j)=\delta_{ij} \qquad(1\le i\le n, 1\le j\le n)
$$
(Kronecker delta) and is uniquely determined by this property. Since we have an isomorphism $\omega\colon V\to V^{**}$, we can define $v_i=\omega^{-1}(\xi_i^*)$ and the set $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is automatically a basis for $V$.

Now, by definition of the isomorphism $\omega$,
$$
\xi_i(v_j)=\omega(v_j)(\xi_i)=\xi_j^*(\xi_i)=\delta_{ji}=\delta_{ij}
$$
so indeed $\{\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n\}$ is the dual basis for $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$.

Comment: Nice answer, +1